# Passing a prop/variable to react router 6 loader function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My routes are working and accessing components and loader functions. I'm trying now to pass variable `filmsPerPage` (which is defined once) to both `Home` component and the `loader` function in

App.js:

```
const App = () => { 
  const filmsPerPage = 12
    
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/',
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Home {...{filmsPerPage}} />,
          loader: () => { loaderHome(filmsPerPage) }
        },
        .................
```

Home.js:

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const { loaderData } = useLoaderData() // get loader data --> null
  console.log(props.filmsPerPage) // printing out correctly: 12
  .......
}
    
export default Home;
    
export function loaderHome(filmsPerPage) {
  console.log(filmsPerPage) --> printing out 12
  return defer({
    loaderData: loadPosts(null, 1, 12, null)
  })
}
```

The prop `filmsPerPage` is passing correctly to `Home.js` component and while it's passing to the `loader` function, the `useLoaderData()` in `Home.js` is returning null which means that although the code in the loader function is working properly, it's not returning a loader object to the component. If I do this in `App.js`, the `useLoaderData()` function (in `Home.js`) will get the data but now the loader function doesn't have the prop:

```
children: [
  {
    index: true,
    element: <Home {...{filmsPerPage}} />,
    loader: loaderHome
  },
```

How could I pass the `filmsPerPage` prop to the `loader` function which will then return loader data to `Home.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader function isn't returning anything. Perhaps reformatted to a more readable format will make this more apparent:

```js
{
  index: true,
  element: <Home {...{filmsPerPage}} />,
  loader: () => {
    loaderHome(filmsPerPage); // <-- not returned!!
  },
}
```

The loader should *still* return the result of calling `loaderHome`.

Examples:

```js
{
  index: true,
  element: <Home {...{filmsPerPage}} />,
  loader: () => {
    return loaderHome(filmsPerPage); // <-- explicit return in function block
  },
}
```

```js
{
  index: true,
  element: <Home {...{filmsPerPage}} />,
  loader: () => loaderHome(filmsPerPage), // <-- implicit arrow function return
}
```

You could even rewrite `loaderHome` to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), e.g. close over in function scope, the `filmsPerPage` argument.

```js
export function loaderHome(filmsPerPage) {
  console.log(filmsPerPage); --> printing out 12

  // Return loader function
  return (loaderArgs) => {
    return defer({
      loaderData:  loadPosts(null, 1, filmsPerPage, null);
    });
  };
}
```

```js
{
  index: true,
  element: <Home {...{filmsPerPage}} />,
  loader: loaderHome(filmsPerPage),
}
```